# Writing output of conditional statements to a file within nested loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, while-loop

I have a with loop where i open two json files and carry out specific comparison within my loops. I have a variety of conditional statements and depending on which condition is met , I want to output the results to a file. Now I am not sure where that would fit within a for loop. I currently have print statements in my loop which concatenate strings and variables. I would like to replace this to write to a file instead.

```
with open('file1.json', 'r') as f, open('file2.json', 'r') as g:
    for cd, pd in zip(f, g):
        if condition:  
            if condition:
                print "I would like to output this to a file":
            else: 
                print "I would like to output this to a file"
        else:  # file names do not match
            print "I would like to output this , str(variable)"
```

Comment: I removed the `python-3.x` tag because you're using print statements, which implies you can't be using Python 3. Please don't tag irrelevant versions.

Comment: No problem @khelwood

Comment: So what is the problem? Why can't you just write to a file instead of using `print`?

Comment: `h.write("This is being written to a file\n")`

Comment: within the print statement , i am also concatenating other variables for example :

print "File", str(current_fn), "with file size", str(current_fs), "is  in range"

Would i just replace the print with h.write @Barmar

Comment: Your question is unclear. 
Please clearly mention what you are doing, what output you want to achieve and whats the current hurdle in achieving that output

Comment: You need to use concatenation: `h.write("File" + str(current_fn) + "with file size" ...)`. Or use a formatting operator to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be simply how to build a string dynamically so you can write it to file. There are (at least) two basic ways to do that:

- Concatenate the parts of your string:

  `text = "File: " + str(current_fn) + ", line: " + str(line_number)`
- Use string formatting:

  `text = "File: {}, line: {}".format(current_fn, line_number)` (new-style) or

  `text = "File: %s, line: %s" % (current_fn, line_number)` (old-style) or

  `text = "File: {filename}, line: {line_number}".format(filename=current_fn, line_number=line_number)` (new-style with named interpolation)

You can also use named-parameters with old-style formatting and if you use Python 3 instead of Python 2, you can also use f-strings.

Then, of course, to write the message:
`h.write(text)` if `h` is a file open for writing.